# Kotlin compiler error: cannot access OkHttpClient

Tags: android, okhttp

I have next problem with a Kotlin compiler:

```
class file for okhttp3.OkHttpClient not found 
Consult the following stack trace for details.
```

I googled it but there is no any solution for me.

This is my dependencies in gradle:

```
    dependencies {
    // Modules
    implementation project(':domain')
    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    // Network
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okHttpVersion"
    implementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:$stethoVersion"
    // DI
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerAdnroidVersion"
    implementation "javax.inject:javax.inject:$javaxVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    // Testing
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    testImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:$runnerVersion"
    testImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockitoCore"
    testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:$mockitoKotlin"
    testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_components_vers"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$androidAnnotationsVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:$androidRunnerVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:rules:$androidRunnerVersion"
}
```

And I can work with this class in code - there is no errors with this class.

But when I try to run application I see this problem. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using proguard or any obfuscation library?

Comment: @DevMike01 this problem actual for `useProguard = false`

Comment: @Artem Could you resolve this issue?

Comment: @anshul yes, but I forgot how I did it)

Comment: I fixed it by providing the dagger dependencies properly.